# strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, steam, steam-web-api

Right Im trying to get the prices for items in my inventory using two different json files. But when it comes to the CS:GO coins they have no price so...

Here is my code:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198050605019/inventory/json/730/2'));
$prices  = json_decode(file_get_contents('prices.json'));

$items = [];


foreach($prices->results as $result){
    $items[$result->market_name] = $result;
}

foreach($json->rgDescriptions as $item){
    if (str_contains([' Coin ', ' coin '], $item->market_name)) continue;
    var_dump($item->market_name . ' - $' . $items[$item->market_name]->current_price);
}
```

And here is the error im getting

```
public static function contains($haystack, $needles)
{
    foreach ((array) $needles as $needle) {
        if ($needle != '' && strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I would prefer it to just ignore the coins altogether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got your parameters the wrong way round!

```
if (str_contains($item->market_name, [' Coin ', ' coin '])) continue;
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error in Laravel 9. Is it deprecated in latest version or what ?

Comment: Got it ! In Laravel 9 we need to use Str::contains() instead of str_contains() !!